# OpenMDAO generating N2 diagram failed

Tags: openmdao

I am trying the OpenMDAO UserGuide tutrial [Visualizing OpenMDAO Model Structure and Connections][1], the IDE tell me that

> "view_tree is deprecated. Please switch to view_model."

but when I import the view_model and call it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/TsingWill/OneDrive/Python Code/Learning/Optimize/OpenMDAO/Tutorial1： Paraboloid.py", line 125, in <module>
    view_model(top)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\devtools\partition_tree_n2.py", line 180, in view_model
    with open(os.path.join(code_dir, 'd3.v4.min.js'), "r") as f:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\openmdao\\devtools\\d3.v4.min.js'
```

What's the matter? my OpenMDAO version is 1.7.2（not sure about this but it's the latest）

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The 1.7.3 release of OpenMDAO, available today via pip should address this problem.

PREVIOUS ANSWER:
I think I have had this error before...it was when I upgraded to 1.7.2 and needed to re-install OpenMDAO to get the js file to show up in the site-packages.  Give that a try?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I get it, it seems that the 1.7.2 version installed using 'pip' command do not contain that file, it should be clone from [github-OpenMDAO](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO) and this problem will not occur

Comment: Yes, after some investigation, the problem lies in our 1.7.2 release.  Things were erroneously left out of a setup.py file, and therefore didn't get put in the release.  I'll be making a 1.7.3 release to rectify that problem, but for now, grabbing the latest on github will get you moving again.